# Why Can't read data From Database Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

```
 mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Name");


        mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Name2").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e(TAG, "App title updated");

                 appTitle = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);


                // update toolbar title

                textGrid.setText(appTitle);
                if (appTitle == "tt"){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,"dsfsdf",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read app title value.", error.toException());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,"Error read Value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

**I store name information that was working a few days ago and the information is stored on firebase Realtime, and now you don't do
it, and nothing goes to Database.**

**in my dependencies i Used**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
```

**and in build Gradle (project)**

```
 dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha2'



    }
```

Comment: is your project connected to firebase?

Comment: yes connected .

Comment: may be you are accidently delete your google-services.json? or changed your SHA-1?

Comment: also
 mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Name2") 
should be 
 mFirebaseInstance.child("Name2")

Comment: Try checking if your firebase rules are updated(allow access to the database).

Comment: Yes, I changed SHA-1

Comment: You need to change it (or add another one) in your firebase project settings

Comment: I add SHA-1 but dint work

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Can you add your storing coding? I only see code that listens for updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments we find a problem, you need to add another one SHA-1, or change existing one. Go to your project. then tap on your project and go to settings. in bottom, tap to add new fingerprint, or delete

[image: step1]

[image: step2]

Comment: I do that , but don't work

Comment: check your permission in database

Comment: How do this... ?

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: but in your code, you didn't set any data, only get